# How do I verify the hash created by fingerprint2.js using the components array

Tags: javascript, fingerprinting

I’m interested in using fingerprint2.js

https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

I’m storing both the hash and the components array being generated.

Is there a way to take the components and then create the hash?

I realize that the user can spoof his browser data and thereby change the the hash , however I want to ensure that the hash itself is real, and not a spoofed string.

Ie:

```
Fingerprint2.get(function (components) {
                     console.log(components);
                     Posttoserver(components);
                 });

/* Get hash , components. Post to server, store the data */
```

What is the function to get the hash? Is it callable separately?
Is there a library or tool that can take a comp array and produce the same hash that the browser generated from the command line?

Like getHash(components)

Answer (score 1):

It would appear in version 2.0 hash and component functions have been decoupled

“Fingerprint2 ships with the murmur hash function that you may use to create a hash fingerprint:”

So this means you can rebuild the hash later on for verification very simply . Problem solved